# Looking for web builder solution that supports self-hosting, AI-based is a plus, has agency pricing

Tags: self-hosting

Looking for suggestions on a web builder tool where I can self-host. If it has some AI assistance, that would be nice for a quick start. Also need a company that has an agency model for pricing.

Been building sites for 20+ years - now I'm looking for speed for mostly simple sites (aka: not commerce). Dumped Dreamweaver years ago, but am not excited by VS Code and Bootstrap anymore.

Thanks!

Looked at: Framer, Durable, CodeDesign